# CssSyntaxError: Unclosed bracket

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss, stylus, stylelint

In my react project,Imported CSS from [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) is throwing error,
After debugging into the css of react-datepicker found out that multiple not:() selector are causing the issue.If I comment that css, Project complies without any error.I am using [stylus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus), [stylelint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint) and [postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss) in my project.
Below is the CSS code which is causing the issue and it is valid syntax

```
range:not(.react-datepicker_day--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__month-text--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__quarter-text--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__year-text--in-selecting-range),
.react-datepicker_month--selecting-range .react-datepickermonth-text--in-range:not(.react-datepicker_day--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__month-text--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__quarter-text--in-selecting-range,
.react-datepicker__year-text--in-selecting-range),
.react-datepicker_month--selecting-range .react-datepickeryear-text--in-range:not(.react-datepickerday--in-selecting-range,.react-datepickermonth-text--in-selecting-range,.react-datepickerquarter-text--in-selecting-range,.react-datepicker_year-text--in-selecting-range) {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #000;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the error
[image: css syntaxerror]

postcss version: 8.4.21
stylus version: 0.59.0
stylelint version: 15.2.0

I created a ticket on postcss but as per them it might be issue with Stylus parser for PostCSS .
Below is the link of ticket
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1818